# Is the title "Project Almanac" an homage to Back to the Future?

Tags: analysis, title, reference, project-almanac

I am not sure why this movie was called Project Almanac.

As far as I remember the protagonists just make up the name out of the blue and never mention it again, so maybe there is no significance at all and it is just a random code word. (One of them also says he wants to be called "Obsidian One" now, which would be another random name as far as I can tell.)

But the more I think about it the more I suspect it might be a homage to Back to the Future 2, one of the greatest time travel movies known to man, which prominently features a sports almanac in the story line that is used to predict future horse racing results.

---

- What is the significance of the movie title "Project Almanac"?
- Is there any hard evidence that it is a hint at the Back to the Future series, for example a statement of the director or writers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Brad told us that the title of the movie is the name of the project
>   that the father was working on.  Is that a nod to Back to the Future?**
>
> STARK: The movie is fraught with sort of Easter eggs and secrets and
>   little moments and things that harken back to many different parts of
>   mythology.  One of which being that, in our head at least, the
>   original people who started designing the blueprints were fans of time
>   travel movies and certainly some wiseass in this sort of DARPA covert
>   operation decided to name it after something he was a fan of.  That
>   was in our heads, at least.  I hope I don’t get sued for that.
>
> **You’re allowed to use that word.  Just don’t call it Grays Sports Almanac.**
>
> STARK: We came up with the word because we wanted to name it after the
>   secret project that it was and we started using – because we’re
>   intelligence junkies – we started actually using a random word
>   generator, which is how they actually do name covert projects, and
>   then that word came up and as soon as that did, we were like, ‘Oh,
>   that makes sense, and that connects back to this because it was this
>   year they probably built it.’  I’d love to take full credit, but
>   somewhere is a website that you just keep pushing spacebar.  We just
>   got lucky that that word came up.

Reference link : [Interview with the writer: **Andrew Stark**](http://collider.com/andrew-stark-project-almanac-interview/)

Comment: Wait, what? They named the movie after something that came up on a random word generator on the internet? How very creative...

Comment: Then how do you explain the camera POV style like Marty McFly used in the movie. Doc Brown's using 2 chronometer to calculate time difference. Even in the movie we see the guy holding booster cable and was pulling it like Doc Brown because they were too short. Sorry, but the movie have many easter eggs from BTTF.